# Is it possible to compute the minimum of a set of numbers modulo a given number in amortized sublinear time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is there a data structure representing a large set `S` of (64-bit) integers, that starts out empty and supports the following two operations:

- `insert(s)` inserts the number `s` into `S`;
- `minmod(m)` returns the number `s` in `S` such that `s mod m` is minimal.

An example:

```
    insert(11)
    insert(15)
    minmod(7) -> the answer is 15 (which mod 7 = 1)
    insert(14)
    minmod(7) -> the answer is 14 (which mod 7 = 0)
    minmod(10) -> the answer is 11 (which mod 10 = 1)
```

I am interested in minimizing the maximal total time spent on a sequence of `n` such operations. It is obviously possible to just maintain a list of elements for `S` and iterate through them for every `minmod` operation; then insert is `O(1)` and minmod is `O(|S|)`, which would take `O(n^2)` time for `n` operations (e.g., `n/2` `insert` operations followed by `n/2` `minmod` operations would take roughly `n^2/4` operations).

So: is it possible to do better than `O(n^2)` for a sequence of `n` operations? Maybe `O(n sqrt(n))` or `O(n log(n))`? If this is possible, then I would also be interested to know if there are data structures that additionally admit removing single elements from `S`, or removing all numbers within an interval.

Comment: If `n` is the number of elements in the array, then this is O(n), surely?  For each element, calculate `x % m`, and keep track of the current minimum.

Comment: sorry,but it needs to insert and query dynamically and answer the queries online,and there are a huge number of operations of inserting and queries.

Comment: I have edited the problem to make it clear.

Comment: Please clarify what `n` is.

Comment: Well I have explained it:"which time complexity is lower than O(nsqrt(n)),in which n is the times of operations".An operation means an inserting or query.I'm sorry for my confusing expression because I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Is there a bound on the modulo?

Comment: I have tried to rewrite the question substantially for language and clarity; feel free to roll back if you feel that I missed something. (Edit should show up once it's been reviewed.)

Comment: @Keith Suppose it's also a 64-bit integer

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge I don't think they can both be O(1) you may be misunderstanding the question

Comment: @aaronman Sorry, for some reason I thought it was always the same modulus

Comment: I'm wondering if a (hypothetical) efficient implementation could lead to a faster-than-currently-best-known algorithm for factorisation.

Comment: If cuda is option, you might want to look into that

Answer (score 7):

Another idea based on balanced binary search tree, as in [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540026/keith)'s answer.

Suppose all inserted elements so far are stored in balanced BST, and we need to compute `minmod(m)`. Consider our set `S` as a union of subsets of numbers, lying in intervals [**0,m-1], [m, 2m-1], [2m, 3m-1]** .. etc. The answer will obviously be among the minimal numbers we have in each of that intervals. So, we can consequently lookup the tree to find the minimal numbers of that intervals. It's easy to do, for example if we need to find the minimal number in **[a,b]**, we'll move left if current value is greater than **a**, and right otherwise, keeping track of the minimal value in **[a,b]** we've met so far.

Now if we suppose that **m** is ***uniformly distributed*** in **[1, 2^64]**, let's calculate the mathematical expectation of number of queries we'll need.

For all **m** in **[2^63, 2^64-1]** we'll need **2** queries. The probability of this is **1/2**.
For all **m** in **[2^62, 2^63-1]** we'll need **4** queries. The probability of this is **1/4**.
...
The mathematical expectation will be **sum[ 1/(2^k) * 2^k ]**, for **k** in **[1,64]**, which is **64** queries.

So, to sum up, the ***average*** `minmod(m)` query complexity will be **O(64*logn)**. In general, if we **m** has unknown upper bound, this will be **O(logm*logn)***. The BST update is, as known, **O(logn)**, so the overall complexity in case of **n** queries will be **O(nlogm*logn)**.

Comment: Well I haven't understood it but it seems to be a great solution.I'd like to confirm if you have made a typing mistake,which is "lying in intervals [0,m-1], [m, 2m-1], [2m, 2m-1]",located at the third line.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, please tell me which part you didn't understand well, and I'll clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much.I have understand it.But it seems that the algorithm only fit random m,and it may run really slow when the special input is given.

Comment: Yes, I especially mentioned uniform distribution. Of course it's possible to give such m which will maximize queries number. However I don't think there's better algo than just checking all the numbers if, let's say, someone who wants to slow you down is choosing bad m on each step.

Comment: Very nice answer. I'd also like to note that you can keep track of the size of the tree and fall back to linear search if the number of intervals you need to check is larger than `1/log(n)`. This will take care of the potential issue @algodynamic is concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer too big for a comment.

Suppose you implement `S` as a balanced binary search tree.

When you seek `S.minmod(m)`, naively you walk the tree and the cost is O(n^2).

However, at a given time during the walk, you have the best (lowest) result so far. You can use this to avoid checking whole sub-trees when:

```
bestSoFar < leftChild mod m
```

and

```
rightChild - leftChild < m - leftChild mod m
```

This will only help much if a common spacing b/w the numbers in the set is smaller than common values of `m`.

**Update the next morning...**

Grigor has better and more fully articulated my idea and shown how it works well for "large" `m`. He also shows how a "random" `m` is typically "large", so works well.

Grigor's algorithm is so efficient for large `m` that one needs to think about the risk for much smaller `m`.
So it is clear that you need to think about the distribution of `m` and optimise for different cases if need be.
For example, it might be worth simply keeping track of the minimal modulus for very small `m`.

But suppose `m ~ 2^32`? Then the search algorithm (certainly as given but also otherwise) needs to check `2^32` intervals, which may amount to searching the whole set anyway.